Behavioral difference between constructing a `Nef_polyhedron_3` directly from OFF file and constructing from a `Polyhedron_3` built from the same file
In CGAL, a Nef_polyhedron_3 can be built directly by loading an OFF file, or by building a Polyhedron_3 by loading the same OFF file and then constructing a Nef_polyhedron_3 from that.
A small example that does the former:
#include "common.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  Nef_polyhedron nef_poly;
  std::ifstream is("test.off", std::ios::in);
  CGAL::OFF_to_nef_3(is, nef_poly);
  is.close();

  return 0;
}

One that does the latter:
#include "common.hpp"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  Polyhedron poly;
  std::ifstream is("test.off", std::ios::in);
  bool success = CGAL::IO::read_OFF(is, poly);
  is.close();
  assert(success);
  assert(poly.is_valid());
  assert(poly.is_closed());

  Nef_polyhedron nef_poly(poly); // <--- A (see below).

  return 0;
}

Here common.hpp contains:
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_OFF_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/OFF_to_nef_3.h>

using Exact_kernel = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
using Polyhedron = CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Exact_kernel>;
using Surface_mesh = CGAL::Surface_mesh<Exact_kernel::Point_3>;
using Nef_polyhedron = CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Exact_kernel>;

From the documentation, I would expect the two to produce the same Nef polyhedron ("same" mathematically speaking). However, I can construct some OFF files for which only the former method works, while the latter fails with
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Assertion_exception'
  what():  CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: ss_circle.has_on(sp)
File: /usr/include/CGAL/Nef_3/polygon_mesh_to_nef_3.h
Line: 253

at the location labeled A.
Here's an OFF that exhibits that behavior:
OFF
5 5 10
-0.193282 0.100467 0.339231
-0.183855 0.102082 0.334972
-0.183473 0.103303 0.332011
-0.181318 0.104688 0.348585
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
3 4 0 1
3 4 1 2
3 4 2 3
3 4 3 0
4 3 2 1 0

Here's one where the two approaches produce the same polyhedron, as I would expect in general:
OFF
8 6 12
 1.0  0.0 1
 0.0  1.0 1
-1.0  0.0 1
 0.0 -1.0 1
 1.0  0.0 0.0
 0.0  1.0 0.0
-1.0  0.0 0.0
 0.0 -1.0 0.0
4 0 1 2 3
4 7 4 0 3
4 4 5 1 0
4 5 6 2 1
4 3 2 6 7

I assume I've misunderstood something in the CGAL documentation for these classes. Is it obvious exactly what that is?

As an addendum, here's a simple visualization of the edges of the OFF that breaks. Nothing too spooky going on there. The orange edges are the ones that make up the boundary of the only non-triangle surface segment.


The first OFF file you provided contains a non-planar facet (4 3 2 1 0), which can't be processed by the Nef_polyhedron_3 constructor. However such facets can be handled by more advanced function CGAL::OFF_to_nef_3(...), which is explicitly stated in its header:

This function creates a 3D Nef polyhedron from an OFF file which
is read from input stream in. The purpose of OFF_to_nef_3
is to create a Nef polyhedron from an OFF file that cannot be handled
by the Nef_polyhedron_3 constructors. It handles double
coordinates while using a homogeneous kernel, non-coplanar facets,
surfaces with boundaries, self-intersecting surfaces, and single
facets. Every closed volume gets marked. The function returns the
number of facets it could not handle.

So, if you split this non-planar facet into two triangles then both OFF-handling functions will be able to process the modified OFF file:
 OFF
5 6 0
-0.193282 0.100467 0.339231
-0.183855 0.102082 0.334972
-0.183473 0.103303 0.332011
-0.181318 0.104688 0.348585
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
3 4 0 1
3 4 1 2
3 4 2 3
3 4 3 0
3 3 1 0
3 3 2 1

ADDITION. The Nef polyhedron, created from the first OFF file with the aid of the CGAL::OFF_to_nef_3 function, can be visualized with the function CGAL:draw(...):

You can see, that the non-planar facet was automatically triangulated by addition of one extra-edge, and it looks like it was done correctly.

Thanks! But surely the face 3 2 1 0 is planar, just not triangular?

@gspr - According to the CGAL::coplanar(...) these four points aren't coplanar. You can make them coplanar (I did that by setting their z-coordinates to 0.34) - then the Nef_polyhedron constructor will be able to process the polygon mesh.

@gspr - BTW, the second OFF file you provided should have six faces

Oh, incredibly that I didn't catch that – you are of course right. Do you know if it's documented anywhere exactly how the Nef OFF reader imposes coplanarity upon the points? Does it look for some minimal adjustment, perhaps, or does it just go with some heuristic (like "wiggle z a bit", like you did)? I definitely have to avoid the latter :)

@gspr - I don't know details about how the OFF_to_nef_3 function treats non-planar facets - but I see that it can create additional edges (see the addition please). It looks like the non-planar facets handling isn't documented clearly enough - they just say that polygons must be planar and add a lot of assertions into CGAL sources.
